# Git changes deleted after stashing with no stash to restore

Tags: git, visual-studio

I was about ready to push my branch and create a pull request when I noticed the branch display in visual studio said 'Unknown Repository'

For some reason I decided to stash my changes. In visual studio I clicked 'Stash All (--include-untracked)'

After this my repository showed correctly and the branch showed correctly. But all my changes were gone and there was no stash to restore.

Is there any way I can get my changes back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news.
I managed to find a list of the stashes in .git/logs/refs/stash

This contained a list of my previous stashes including the last stash that caused all the troubles.

This line has 2 hashes. The first hash was the same as one of the hashes of a stash above. So I took the 2nd hash and ran this command in the package manager console of visual studio:

git stash apply {StashHash}

This applied the changes and I could then commit and push to the remote branch.

I hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: That points to a bug in VS, because `.git/logs/refs/stash` *is* the stash stack and `git stash` works by using `refs/stash` plus that stash stack. (Given how complex VS is with all of its plug-ins, this might be a bug introduced by some set of plugins you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to provided answer, switching between the last pushed branch and the current branch (which I was not able to see the stashes) did the trick for me.

Also, as long as you have the .git/logs/refs/stash, no need to worry. It is just the Visual Studio messed up. You can always apply stash via git stash apply command as mentioned in the other anwser.